# --no-clobber still overwrites file if --html-extension used in wget?

Tags: html, wget, overwrite

I have a script for downloading all of my Chrome Bookmarks. I use wget with the --html-extension because some of the bookmarks end in .php and can't be opened by a web browser unless --html-extension option is used. The problem I am having is that when I use --html-extension with --no-clobber, It doesn't recognize that most of the files are already there for some reason, so it goes through the whole process of redownloading stuff it already has.

An example:
    wget -nc http://www.test.com/
run once will save the file like it is supposed to. if you run it again then it will say the file already there so not retrieving. that is the operation i would expect.

however, delete the file that was just saved and run:
    wget -nc http://www.test.com/ --html-extension
and then run that same command again. it overwrites the file instead of saying file already there. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the html suffix is added, wget can't tell what remote file you want to compare it to.

man wget: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wget

======================

--html-extension

If a file of type application/xhtml+xml or text/html is downloaded
   and the URL does not end with the regexp .[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]?, this
   option will cause the suffix .html to be appended to the local
   filename.  This is useful, for instance, when you're mirroring a
   remote site that uses .asp pages, but you want the mirrored pages
   to be viewable on your stock Apache server.  Another good use for
   this is when you're downloading CGI-generated materials.  A URL
   like http://site.com/article.cgi?25 will be saved as arti-
   cle.cgi?25.html.

**Note that filenames changed in this way will be re-downloaded every
   time you re-mirror a site, because Wget can't tell that the local
   X.html file corresponds to remote URL X (since it doesn't yet know
   that the URL produces output of type text/html or application/xhtml+xml.**  To prevent this re-downloading, you must use -k
   and -K so that the original version of the file will be saved as
   X.orig.

Comment: I haven't verified this yet, but it sounds legit. Thank you for taking the time to answer.